# My ng-model is not updating first time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am having a problem with ng-model .When i am adding tag from suggestion list its not updating model value until i am not deleting tags and adding again.In my project its working fine but for plunker only its happening.Please check this out and help me..

thank you..

Here is my html:-

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags2" display-property="tagName" on-tag-added="getTags()" id="target">
                          <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length="2"></auto-complete>

                 </tags-input>
                 <p>{{tags2}}</p>
```

Here is my js:-

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTagsInput', 'ui.bootstrap']);
  app.controller(
    'myController',

  function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.tagsValues =[];
    $scope.loadTags = function(query) {



        return $http.get('tags.json');
    };

    $scope.getTags = function() {


        $scope.tagsValues = $scope.tags2.map(function(tag) {
            return tag.tagId;
        });


    alert(" Tag id is :"+ $scope.tagsValues);

    };


  });
```

Here is my plunker:-

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Mr2qk2S2RvGJLevf2UI?p=preview

Comment: If it's working fine in your project, why are you worried about it not working in a plunker?

Comment: Actually i have to send this piece of work to my senior for  review..so i need to send plunker link...Do you have any idea what's going wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do to make this work, is define and initialize the variable $scope.tags2 first:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTagsInput', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller(
'myController',

function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.tagsValues = '';
   $scope.tags2 = [];

    $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
        return $http.get('tags.json');
    };

    $scope.getTags = function() {

        $scope.tagsValues = $scope.tags2.map(function(tag) {
            return tag.tagId;
        });

        alert(" Tag id is :"+ $scope.tagsValues);

    };

});
```

See my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3f8kLBnexOXg5gwmldL?p=preview